# onClick completely remove a specific DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

HTML page .....................................................................

```
   <form:form method="post" action="saveMiData.action" id="minorityForm"
                commandName="MinInterestModel">
                <div id="addMoreDiv">
                <label id="validNumber" style="display: none; color: #b94a48;"><spring:message
                                    code="Minority.validNumber" /><font color="#b94a48">*</font></label>
                    <div id="preacq" class="MICss">
                        <div id="linkopen">
                            <div class="span5">
                                <label class="abc" style="margin-bottom: 1px;"> <spring:message
                                        code="MinorityInterest.elementName" /></label>
                                <form:select id="glListName0" path="glElementId"
                                    name="glListName" class="input-block-level" size="1" multiple="bbn">
                                </form:select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="span5">
                                <label class="abc" style="margin-bottom: 1px;"> <spring:message
                                        code="MinorityInterest.AccountType" /></label>
                                <form:select path="accountType" id="accountName0"
                                    name="accountName" class="input-block-level" multiple="bbn">
                                    <option value="0">select</option>
                                    <option value="1">Debit</option>
                                    <option value="2">Credit</option>
                                </form:select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="span5">

                                <label class="abc" style="margin-bottom: 1px;"><spring:message
                                        code="MinorityInterest.preAcq" /></label> <input type="text"
                                    name="preAcqSurPlus" id="preacqas0" class="input-block-level abc"
                                    path="preAcqSurPlus"></input>
                            </div>

                            <div class="span5">
                                <label class="abc" style="margin-bottom: 1px;"> <spring:message
                                        code="MinorityInterest.Share" /></label> <input type="text"
                                    name="Shares" id="share0" path="Shares" class="input-block-level abc"></input>
                            </div>

                            <div class="span2" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                            <div class="add_remove">
                                                <a><img onclick="addMore()"
                                                    src="<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/img/Add-field.png" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="add_remove">
                                                <a><img onclick="removeMI(this)" src= "<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/img/remove-field.png" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function addMore() {
                            //  alert("adddiv");
                                $("#preacq").clone().attr('id', 'preacq'+ cloneCount++).appendTo("#addMoreDiv");
                            }

                        </script>
    <script>

function removeMI(an){
//  alert($(this).attr('id'));
$(this).remove();
            alert("vaibhavremove"+an);

             //  alert($('#preacq0').attr('id','preacq0'+ cloneCount--).remove());

            if(cloneCount==1){
                  alert("No more textbox to remove");
                  return false;
               }   

        //  cloneCount--;
               $("#preacq" + cloneCount).remove();
}
</script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span5" style="float: left;width:38%">
            <label class="abc" style="margin-bottom: 1px; margin-top:67px;  font-size: 17px; margin-left: 347px;"> <spring:message
                                        code="MinorityInterest.TotalAmount" /></label>
                </div>

                <div class="span5" style="float: right;">
                    <input type="text" style="margin-top: 67px;margin-left: -135px;width: 211px;">
                </div>
                <div class="span5" style="float: right;">
                    <input type="text" style="margin-top:67px;margin-left: -158px;width: 211px;">
                </div>
                <form:hidden path="parenCompanyId" id="PcId"/>
                <form:hidden path="childCompanyId" id="CcId"/>
                <form:hidden path="financialYearId" id="FyId"/>
                <form:hidden path="reportingPeriodId" id="rPId"/> 
                <div class="span6" style="float: right; margin-right: 0%">
                    <!-- <input id="saveMI" class="" type="button" value="Save" onclick="saveMI();"> -->
                    <button id="saveButtonId" name="save" value="save" onclick="saveMI();"
                        style="height: 30px; width: 50px;position: fixed; top: 627px;">save</button>
                </div>

            </form:form>
        </div>
My approach on removal function:

    function removeMI(){
        alert("vaibhavremove");
        //  alert($('#preacq0').attr('id','preacq0'+ cloneCount--).remove());
        if(cloneCount==1){
            alert("No more textbox to remove");
            return false;
        }   
        cloneCount--;
        $("#preacq0" + cloneCount).remove();
    }
```

It works fine but my requirement is when click on minus button, the selected div will be removed, not the last one, as I'm creating the div `id` dynamically.

Code for creating div `id`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addMore() {
        //  alert("adddiv");
        $("#preacq0").clone().attr('id', 'preacq0'+ cloneCount++).appendTo("#addMoreDiv");                          
    }
</script>
```

Remove button markup:

```
    <div class="add_remove"> 
        <a>
            <img onclick="removeMI()" src= "<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/img/remove-field.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see relevant HTML markup for the remove button. Anyway, you should use relevant transversal methot to target specific DIV. It sounds like all these IDs are useless

Comment: @wolff   
           <div class="add_remove">
            <a><img onclick="removeMI()" src= "<%=Config.getStaticURL()%>resources/img/remove-field.png" /></a>
           </div>
          </div>

Comment: this is the html markup for remove button

Comment: Post it in question itself, this is unreadable in comment. BTW, a jsFiddle would make it clearer

Comment: You might want to approach this situation a little differently. Rather than handling the number of DIVs you have, you can manage the DIVs is modular way. So adding a DIV will make a new instance, and removing a DIV will remove itself.

Comment: @ElliotM can you please elaborate it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aaki/hMJEy/1/ - This is an example that you should follow.

Comment: my logic works properly but it remove last created DIV ,suppose I have 5 DIv with Id 1 2 3 4 5 respectively if i delete 2 one it will deleted second one

Comment: I cannot understand your HTML structure - it has no sense actually... If you want someone to properly answer your question, you should properly show your HTML. At least one **complete** HTML element which you want to remove.

Comment: @phillip why downvote to my question,see the attached file and html code that i posted if you need anything tell me

Comment: @phillip given the html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done. The logic behind your script however is totally wrong.

Let me explain:

- What gonna happen if someone attempt to remove the *main instance* (`#preacq`) that has to be cloned?
- What if someone want o clone the *instance* where the "clone" button is attached to (otherwise why to place "clone" button inside each *instance* but copy the *main*)?
- Dealing with `id`'s is overkill for that purposes. The *main instance* include elements with their own `id` attributes (like: `select id="glListName0"`). Therefore number of elements with the same `id` is increased each time you clone the *main instance*. Keep in mind that the `id` of each DOM element **must be unique**
- Since each instance has "clone" and "remove" buttons, the *clone instance* should be attached right **after** the *instance* that has been cloned, not at the end of the list (otherwise - once again - why to place "clone" button inside each *instance*?).
- Clicking "delete" button in *main instance*, you're reducing `cloneCount` but **not** deleting any elements, since it has no number attached to its `id` attribute but has active "delete" button.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28644408/962734) provided by *@imsheth* is somehow correct. You should definitely avoid dealing with `id`'s when comes to `.clone()` and use scenario where you could operate on classes and use "parental" style selectors. Otherwise, you **have to** care about each element `id` inside cloned instance.

---

### Why your script does not remove the instance you want?

Each time you press "clone" button, the `cloneCount` value gets increased by `1`.:

```
function addMore() {
    $("#preacq").clone().attr('id', 'preacq'+ cloneCount++).appendTo("#addMoreDiv");
    // say, you cloned instance 5 times, so the "cloneCount" value is now 5
}
```

When comes to delete, you're actually checking the **latest** value of `cloneCount` (which actually represents also the **latest** created element):

```
function removeMI(){
    // because you've created 5 elements, the current "cloneCount" value is 5:
    $("#preacq" + cloneCount).remove();
    // the above will delete "#preacq5" element, which is the latest created.
}
```

**How to repair this?**

I won't focus on another issues there, since the actual question is how to remove a specific DIV based on `id`. So there's an example of a quick fix:

```
function addMore(){
    var cloned = $("#preacq").clone().attr('id', 'preacq'+ cloneCount++);
    // add "data-parent-id" attribute to the "remove" button (to indicate which div should be deleted when this button is clicked):
    cloned.find('.add_remove a img').attr('data-parent-id', '#preacq'+ (cloneCount-1));
    cloned.appendTo("#addMoreDiv");
}

// pass the clicked button (btn) to the function:
function removeMI(btn){
    // get the element id from data attribute of the button:
    $($(btn).data('parent-id')).remove();
}
```

I'd however use *@imsheth* solution.

Comment: @vaib , take a look at **EDIT** section. This should fix all of your issues.

Comment: can we change the id of each element dynamically for example  text box id and dropdown list id as we do in div

Comment: validate if one value selected from 1st i.e.(glelementList in my case) drop down list not selected again.

Comment: before submit button how validate the selected value from dropdown not selected again it show the message error  of the list is selected once in my scnerio of first drop down. my approach is....

Answer (score 2):

```
// For deleting article row
$(document).on('click','.delete-article',function() {
    var selectedRowForDeletion = $(this).closest(".dynamic-new-row");
    selectedRowForDeletion.remove();
});
```

Where:

`.delete-article` = class of the remove button/image

`.dynamic-new-row` = class of every row in div/tr to be removed

`selectedRowForDeletion` = object of the selected row to be removed

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but it does not work, i want remove on id basis

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what you are doing here, but if you are dynamically creating the rows, than they are likely not getting the "delete" function assigned to the minus image you are adding to the dom after the page has loaded. If you pass the assignment through the body (or a parent container) than they will the minus sign will work even if it is added to the dom later. Use this type of function assignment sparingly, I generally only do it this way in these types of situations.

```
$('#minorityForm').on('click', '.myMinusDiv', function(){ alert("minus was clicked") });
```

Comment: thanks i am trying to only delete the selected current div on onClick function